# Vagrant VMs on Multiple Physical Machines

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

I see that Vagrant has an AWS plugin that supports using Vagrant to provision and run multiple ec2 instances.  Does this functionality exist outside of AWS?

Usage Example: Currently I have 5 VMs on a single machine - this was straightforward to setup and manage via the VagrantFile.  I have access now to another 3 machines and want to manage these with 2 VMs on one machine and a single VM on each additional machine.  All machines are connected on a private network via a switch and a public wifi network.

Clearly, I could manage these with individual vagrant files across the physical machine (multi-provisioning on the one where I want 2 VMs).  This seems to defeat the purpose of Vagrant though.

I suspect I am missing some obvious documentation as it seems natural to use Vagrant for managing a physically distributed system of VMs.